# Directions of explode transition between fragments

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, android-transitions

I've implemented a transition between two fragments with an explode animation (Standard google transition -> http://goo.gl/tE5xzl). Is there any opportunity to set the direction of the explosion?

The problem is, when I pop the backstack to my fragment before, I get a random animation with a different direction of the explosion. That looks a kind of confusing for the user.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you found anything?